# App Size increasing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sharekit

I have integrated sharekit in my iPhone Application.My app used to be around 1.5MB and all of a sudden it became 6.3 MB after integrating sharekit.And I am using only Twitter and Facebook Sharing.Is there a way to Reduce the size of my app?.or is there any other way for sharing? 
My Deployment Target is 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use ImageOptim to reduce the file size of your images. Just download, open and drag and drop a folder or all your images onto the interface.

http://imageoptim.com/

There is even a case study on how well this tool can be used to shrink your iOS-Apps:

http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html

Additionally I would delete the ShareKit components you do not need.

Answer (score 3):

ShareKit contains Delicious,DiigoEvernote,Facebook,Flickr,FoursquareV2,Google Reader,Instapaper,LinkedIn,Pinboard,Read It Later,Readability,Tumblr,Twitter,Vkontakte sharing files...

If You are using only FaceBook and Twitter,then delete the remaining files...

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer it this way instead of having dependency on share kit. you can go for DETwitterEngine for twitter and facebook framework for facebook.